# How to manipulate awk variable NF in zsh?

Tags: awk, zsh

I have a simple command line:

```
uptime | awk '{print $(NF - 2)}'
```

In a bash shell, this works without a hitch, but when I run it in zsh, I get the following error:

```
title:5: command not found: NF
```

As usual this will be a pilot error (me not grokking how expansion works in zsh), but I cannot figure out what to do to get the same command to work in zsh.

[Edit]

The zsh version is 4.3.11 on OSX, and the output from `set -xv; uptime | awk '{print $(NF - 2)}'` is:

```
$ set -xv; uptime | awk '{print $(NF - 2)}'
title:5: command not found: NF
+zsh:3> uptime
+zsh:3> awk '{print $(NF - 2)}'
0.51
+precmd:1> title '%15<..<%~%<<' '%n@%m: %~'                                                                           
+title:1> [ '' '!=' true ']'
+title:2> [[ xterm-256color == screen* ]]
+title:4> [[ xterm-256color == xterm* ]]
+title:5> print -Pn '\e]2;%n@%m:\ %~\a'
+title:6> print -Pn '\e]1;%15\<..\<%~%\<\<\a'
+zsh:4> git_prompt_info
+git_prompt_info:1> ref=+git_prompt_info:1> ref='' 
+git_prompt_info:1> return
+zsh:4> vi_mode_prompt_info
+vi_mode_prompt_info:1> echo ''
```

So apparently the awk command works, but my terminal customization is borked.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior, which version of zsh are you using?
Could you post the output of: `set -xv; uptime | awk '{print $(NF - 2)}'`

Comment: Could you please update your post and provide the exact command sequence used to reproduce the issue. It seems that the following awk code `$( ... )` is interpreted by the shell (as command substitution). I suppose that when you quote the dollar sign `\$( ... )` the code will run fine.

Comment: Could you try the fork a new instance of zsh with `zsh -f`  and re-run the pipeline? It seems there is a problem with your rc file.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `title:5: command not found: NF`

This error message shows an error in a function called `title`, which by the name presumably sets your terminal's title to the command being run. The subsequent transcript shows `title` being called by [`precmd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-precmd), which is called when a command has finished executing, just before showing the next prompt. But the error is actually triggered by [`preexec`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-preexec), which is called just before running a command. This function is defined in your `~/.zshrc` (or perhaps `/etc/zshrc`, or in a file that either of them calls).

I can't tell exactly what is wrong without seeing the code, but it looks like the command string is being expanded in some way. Perhaps you have the `prompt_subst` option set and are printing the command through `print -P`? You need to escape the command. In particular, do not print it through `print -P`, print it through `print -r` and take care of literal control characters. Something like:

```
print -r ${${${${(qqqq)1}#\$\'}%\'}//\\\'/'}
```

Comment: You are right. I used a prepackaged zsh-setup (oh-my-sh) which in one of the imported files defines preexec. I have started from scratch with my setup, free of imported cruft. Zsh is nice, but now I will try to learn from scratch instead of blindly applying a prepackaged setup.